# SQL Increment count on repeat values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Not sure how to ask this question, I'm not looking for the total count of a value in a column, rather I want to incrementally count repeat values.  For example:

If my table looks like this:

```
1, ken
2, ken
3, adam
4, ken
5, adam
6, dan
```

I want to add a column during my select that tags duplicates with an incremental number like this:

```
1, ken, 1
2, ken, 2
3, adam, 1
4, ken, 3
5, adam, 2
6, dan, 1
```

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)?

Comment: Sorry, Microsoft 2008R2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this via [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with a `PARTITION` on your second column, ordering by the first:

```
Select  Col1, 
        Col2, 
        Row_Number() Over (Partition By Col2 Order By Col1 Asc) As Col3
From    YourTable
```