# SQL incremental count of records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am looking to incrementally count records which have the same value in a field, while resetting the count for a new value.
 Example Below:

```
| 22 | 1 |
| 22 | 2 | 
| 22 | 3 |
| 33 | 1 | 
| 33 | 2 |
| 44 | 1 |
```

Any Ideas? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873817/sql-increment-count-on-repeat-values) is close but the Row_Number() function does not work for me

Comment: Do you have any other columns in the table, such as a unique id on each row?

Comment: Lots of ideas, but we want to see yours first. What have you researched, tried, and found to not produce your desired output?

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is a column which has a unique id on each row. This column is not an ordered sequence, nor is it in any particular order

Comment: have you ever searched about `windows analytic functions` ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Correct me if I'm wrong, but Window Functions are not available on Access (or has that changed)? Although... If I had to do a Google search to solve this one it would be "Row_Number() OVER () on Access" and I'll bet that would yield quite a lot of solutions.

Comment: @JNevill I don't know if exists for Access, but I thought that contains a function like `row_number()` as a DBMS. Instead of telling the direct address (row_number() over() (partition by..order by)), I'd like to canalize him to learn by researching for the concept generically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row numbers in query result using Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279320/row-numbers-in-query-result-using-microsoft-access)

Comment: @JNevill, I just did that exact Google search and found the correct answer in the very first result.

Comment: Well... doing that google search and learning about window functions and other fun stuff that every other RDBMS supports is just going to make you hate that you are stuck doing whatever you are doing on Access. Hate bumming people out late in the day (perhaps you are over seas though and it's still early morning. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t as t2
        where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.? <= t.?
       ) as incremental_count
from t;
```

`?` is a placeholder for the column that uniquely identifies each row.